# 12.04 ext4 - cannot create regular file/No space left - with a lot of space and inodes

Tags: ext4

This seems similar:
[EXT4 "No space left on device (28)" incorrect](https://serverfault.com/questions/384541/ext4-no-space-left-on-device-28-incorrect)
but there is no explanation

I created an ext4 filesystem on a RAID 1 array with:

```
mke2fs -t ext4 -T small /dev/md0
```

tune2fs -l >> http://pastebin.com/P5eKXmgC

tried this too:

```
mke2fs -t ext4 -b 1024 /dev/md0
```

tune2fs -l >> http://pastebin.com/ujLtE95L

Copying a single directory with many tiny files I get:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/mnt/storage_temp/pics/pic3412.jpg': No space left on device
```

space used 5%

inodes used 1%

I manually tried:

```
cp /source/test1.jpg /mnt/storage_temp/pics/test1.jpg --- error
cp /source/test1.jpg /mnt/storage_temp/pics/test2.jpg --- ERROR
cp /source/test1.jpg /mnt/storage_temp/pics/test3.jpg --- no error
```

Notes: RAID 1 disks are error free. I tried `mv` instead of `cp` and got the same thing. I tried omitting `-T small` with no effect

Can somebody help me understand this magic?

Comment: Please correct your question for internal consistency and don't just blindly copy from another forum.

Comment: The site you are looking for is [google](http://google.com).

Comment: @MikeyB : Where did he copy this question from?

Comment: please let me know what's unclear, i'll try to improve it. it's irrelevant where else i might have posted this question. what matters is that this might be the only place with the answer if you can actually help.

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/md0`.

Comment: idea is to have "block_size = 1024", otherwise tiny files waste space, both of these game me the same error around the 10GB mark:

mke2fs -t ext4 -T small
http://pastebin.com/P5eKXmgC

mke2fs -b 1024
http://pastebin.com/ujLtE95L

Answer (score 0):

How small is that partition? According to `man mke2fs`, the `-T small` gets automatically used if the partition size is between 3 - 512 megabytes. Is the partition that small? If not, do you really need that mke2fs option?

Comment: 2TB drive, single partition, the "-T small" was intended to get the 1024 block size but i also tried "-b 1024" instead and the result was the same

Comment: So, my another question: do you have a rationale for that `-T small`?